# Javascript - additional space from textContent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to get the text from an element, remove some of the string, add a question mark & then place the **updated string** into another element

However, when the element is returned, the markup generates additional unwanted space before & also puts the question mark on an entirely new line within the element.

This is what is returned from a console log

[image: console log]
Code Example

```js
// Set Variables for Dynamic Copy Function

let choiceNode = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
let dynamicCopyNode = document.querySelector('.dynamic-copy');

// Update the text type on dynamic copy & append a question mark + remove 'The '

function updateChoice() {

 let choiceSelected = this.textContent + '?';
 let choiceSelectedTrim = choiceSelected.replace('The ', '');
 dynamicCopyNode.textContent = choiceSelectedTrim;

}


// Click listener to trigger the function

Array.from(choiceNode).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', updateChoice);
});
```

```html
<form>
 <div class="choice-wrapper">
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="1">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The first choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="2">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The second choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="3">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The third choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="4">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The fourth choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="error-wrap"> 
   <label class="error" for="choice" generated="true"></label> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="copy-wrapper">
  <div class="variable-copy">
   <p>Why did you choose</p>
   <h1 class="dynamic-copy"></h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a return like so **first choice?**

Comment: You need the text content of the `p` tag, not the whole div.

Comment: Oh darn - I understand now. However when I try to get the closest `.name` from the clicked `choice` it returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the `textContent` of the `p` tag, not the whole div.

```js
// Set Variables for Dynamic Copy Function

let choiceNode = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
let dynamicCopyNode = document.querySelector('.dynamic-copy');

// Update the text type on dynamic copy & append a question mark + remove 'The '

function updateChoice() {
    // ======================= next line changed
 let choiceSelected = this.querySelector('.name').textContent + '?';
 let choiceSelectedTrim = choiceSelected.replace('The ', '');
 dynamicCopyNode.textContent = choiceSelectedTrim;

}


// Click listener to trigger the function

Array.from(choiceNode).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', updateChoice);
});
```

```html
<form>
 <div class="choice-wrapper">
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="1">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The first choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="2">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The second choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="3">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The third choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="choice">
   <input type="radio" name="choice" id="one" value="4">
   <label for="one">
    <p class="name">The fourth choice</p>
   </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="error-wrap"> 
   <label class="error" for="choice" generated="true"></label> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="copy-wrapper">
  <div class="variable-copy">
   <p>Why did you choose</p>
   <h1 class="dynamic-copy"></h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you sir... Been doing my head in all morning!! I was trying to find the set a new variable then find the text for that element... It continually returned null... Looking back - I have no idea why it wasn't working for me

Comment: I was setting a global variable of `choiceLabel = document.querySelector('.name');` then within the function i set a new variable `choiceText = this.choiceLabel.textContent;` this was returning undefined.